# RAD publishing the application to IHS and WAS

Tags: rad, websphere-7, ibmhttpserver

We are developing a Dynamic Web project using RAD which will run on WAS 7.0. We have configured WAS 7.0 within RAD to run the application directly from RAD. We also have
a web server setup and we need the static files in our Dynamic Web project to be served from Web server.

Unfortunately when we run the application from RAD, it doesn't add the information in plugin.xml file of web server. So we checked this in `<WebApplication_Name>/Manage Modules` section
in WAS Admin console. We are not able specify the web server target also there.

Is there anything that we can do to tell RAD to publish the application both to WAS and IHS? Could you please assist?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this cannot be done using the RAD IDE out-of-the-box, as it just publishes your appication to WAS.

A solution to this would be to build and publish the application using a tool like **Ant** and place in your build script an extra step to appropriately change the plugin-cfg file.